# Open SSL Connection to mysql database with DriverManager from java

Tags: java, ssl

I want to open ssl connection from java to MySQL servers.
For each server has its own certificate files, therefore the use of this

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","...");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","...");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","...");
```

is not suitable.

After searching I realized that it is necessary to use **TrustManagerFactory**, **KeyManagerFactory**, but can not understand.

Maybe there is a ready example? Or i need to set keyStore, trustStore to url connection?

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a keystore at all unless the server requires a client certificate, and there's no reason why you can't use the same client certificate for all the servers, and therefore why you need more than one keystore.

Ergo you *can* use `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and friends.

You do need a truststore, but only if the servers have one or more self-signed certificates, and there's no reason why they can't all be in the same truststore.

Ergo you *can* use `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.

Comment: I have CA File, CERT File and Key File, what i must to set ещ url database connection?

Comment: If you're asking how to make MySQL server talk SSL you're off topic for SO. If you're asking something else it isn't clear what.

Comment: I need to connect existing MySQL server with ssl.
On it are all the settings for ssl